# Legend in loa plot

Tags: r, legend

I'm trying to create a bubbleplot in R with this command:

```
GoogleMap(zfit ~ lat*lon,xlim=c(12,13),ylim=c(45.1,45.9),main="Dati anno ",panel = function(...) panel.zcasePiePlot(...,col=rgb(102/256,178/256,255/256,alpha=0.6)))
```

I'm using package `loa`. Here you can find the objects: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47720440/StackOverFlow.RData

Here's the plot:
[image]

The legend is different from what is plotted. How can be fixed?

Comment: to clarify, you want the legend all blue? or the plot blu and pink?

Comment: Legend all blue, bubbles as big as plot

Comment: what happens if you add `col.regions=c("blue")` or `#66B2FF` ?

Comment: If i set: `GoogleMap(zfit ~ lat*lon,col.regions=c("blue"),xlim=c(12,13),ylim=c(45.1,45.9),main=paste("Dati anno ",TimePoints[j],sep=""),panel = panel.zcasePiePlot)` i find this error: Error in brewer.pal(9, col.regions) : 
  blue is not a valid palette name for brewer.pal